# Display toast from a thread into main activity

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-toast

I am creating an Android app in which I called a service C from main activity A. From the service C I am calling an instance of class B which extends a thread. Now I need to display a message for the user from this class B. I tried using Handler class and the code I used is

**IN CLASS B EXTENDING THREAD:**

```
Message status = someHandler.obtainMessage();
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("SOMETHING", "dist");
        status.setData(data);

        someHandler.sendMessage(status);
```

**IN SERVICE C:**

```
Handler someHandler = new Handler(){

     //this method will handle the calls from other threads.       
     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg.getData().getString("SOMETHING"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
};
```

Now when I run this I am expecting a toast to be displayed in the main UI activity A. But it is not working.

Comment: "Not working" is not a very useful fault report - it probably is not enough for readers to work out what is going wrong - so this old question can probably be closed as lacking a [mcve]. In the unlikely event you still want an answer, please edit the question to include more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the context, depending on how service C is shown, getBaseContext() is not always proper. You could try 'this' or calling the context staticly.